# Is there a way to select certain elements within an element collection in VBA

Tags: html, vba, loops, if-statement, screen-scraping

I'm still new to VBA and data scraping. I would like to check if there is a way to select certain elements within an element collection. My VBA code is as follows:

```
Sub Refresh()
    Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim Price As Variant, Change As Variant, Volume As Variant
    Dim HTMLTag As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

    XMLPage.Open "GET", Mapping.Range("B2"), False
    XMLPage.send
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText

    Set HTMLTable = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("stockinfocol1")

    For Each HTMLTag In HTMLTable
    Debug.Print HTMLTag.innerText
    Next HTMLTag
End Sub
```

The results from debug.print is as follows:

> Last Traded Share Price 1.200
>
> Change -0.030 / -2.44%
>
> Volume Traded 1,291,800
>
> Day Range 1.190 - 1.250
>
> Last Traded Date 2020-05-19

Remarks

However, I only need certain elements within this collection (eg: Last Traded Share Price and Volume Traded). Is there a way to do an For each and IF statement to sieve the elements that I want?

HTML code is here for your reference:

```
<div class="stockinfocol1"><div title="AIMS APAC REIT Share Price" class="stockinfocol1row1"><span class="label">Last Traded Share Price </span><span class="value red">1.200</span></div><div class="stockinfocol1row"><span class="label">Change </span><span class="value red" label="change">-0.030 / -2.44%</span></div><div title="AIMS APAC REIT Volume Traded" class="stockinfocol1row"><span class="label">Volume Traded </span><span class="value" label="volume">1,218,700</span></div><div title="AIMS APAC REIT Day Price Range" class="stockinfocol1row"><span class="label">Day Range </span><span class="value" label="Day Range">1.190 - 1.250</span></div><div title="AIMS APAC REIT Last Traded Date" class="stockinfocol1row"><span class="label">Last Traded Date </span><span class="value" label="Last Traded Date">2020-05-19</span></div><div title="AIMS APAC REIT Remarks" class="stockinfocol1row"><span class="label">Remarks </span><span class="value" label="Remarks"> </span></div></div>
```

Comment: Probably a better way but you *could* do something like `If HTMLElement.innertext Like "Last Traded*" Then 'Do something ElseIf HTMLElement.innertext Like "Volume Traded*" Then 'Do something ElseIf...` Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try such an approach

```
Sub Test()
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument, post As Object, sPriceTraded As String, sVolumeTraded As String, i As Long
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "C:\Sample.html", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    sPriceTraded = "Last Traded Share Price"
    sVolumeTraded = "Volume Traded"
    Set post = html.querySelectorAll(".stockinfocol1 div")
    With post
        For i = 0 To .Length - 1
            With .Item(i)
                If InStr(.innerText, sPriceTraded) Then
                    Debug.Print Trim(Replace(.innerText, sPriceTraded, vbNullString))
                End If
                If InStr(.innerText, sVolumeTraded) Then
                    Debug.Print Trim(Replace(.innerText, sVolumeTraded, vbNullString))
                End If
            End With
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```